# PowerBI - Calculate Max Date between set of Dates

Tags: powerbi, max, dax

I am trying to calculate the max date for a certain criteria between a set of dates. Please see the below data, and expected output below.

```
Data:

> Investment    Date
+ AAPL          10/1/2020  
+ SPY           3/15/2022
+ LULU          3/18/2020 
+ LULU          8/12/2020 
+ SPY           10/15/2020 
+ APPL          12/5/2020 
+ AAPL          11/12/2021
> 
> Expected Output: 
+ LULU          8/12/2020 
+ SPY           10/15/2020 
+ APPL12/5/2020
```

I want the output to find the max date that was used for only a certain year that I can set. For the expected output above, I am looking to get the max date for 2020 for the investment.

Help on this will be very much appreciated.

I have attempted using MAXX & MAX, but I can't seem to figure out how to set the start/end date for the max functions to work between.

Comment: You may want to check how to add filter conditions to your CALCULATEd measure.

Answer (score 0):

First step is to get year from the date column and filter 2020 in the transform data section.

and then use [group by](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/group-by) `Investment` and for the operation pick max from the dropdown and pick the date column from the table.